# push.apply not working on AngulaJS forEach

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying create a multidimensional object using forEach loop of AngularJS.

```
$scope.area_element = [];

$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/elements'}).
    then(function(res){
        $scope.elements = res.data;
        angular.forEach($scope.elements, function(itemE){
            $scope.area_element.push({cost_element: itemE.cost_element, element_desc: itemE.element_desc});
            angular.forEach($scope.pm_area_ae, function(item, key){
                $http.get('api/work_ordersmae/'+ $rootScope.isNum +'/'+ $scope.itemC+'/'+ item.rnem_area +'/'+ itemE.cost_element).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    $scope.area_element.push.apply($scope.area_element, data);
                });


            });

        });

});
```

The HTML

```
<pre><div class="row col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Cost Element</th>
          <th class="text-center" ng-repeat="ar in pm_area_ae">{{ar.rnem_area}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="e in area_element">
          <td>{{e.cost_element}} {{e.element_desc}}</td>
          <td class="text-right" ng-repeat="elem in e">{{elem.area_cost}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div></pre>
```

It doesn't work. The area_cost value doesn't show up. but i'm getting multiple [object] on console log.

Am I using push.apply(); correctly for this type of function? Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends if `data` is an array of parameters that you want to apply to the `push` method. If `data` is just a single object then you might want to use `$scope.area_element.push.call($scope.area_element, data)` instead. If `data` can be a single object OR an array of items, then use: `$scope.area_element.push.apply($scope.area_element, [].concat(data));`

Comment: Why are using using push.apply as you are giving it the this context is will already have

Comment: I want it to be like this [{cost_element: '602', rnem_area: {area: 'nl1', area_cost: '2000'},{area: 'nl2', area_cost: '1000'}}]